# Can $G≅H$ and $G≇H$ in two different views?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Can $G≅H$ and $G≇H$ in two different views?

We have two isomorphic groups $G$ and $H$, so $G≅H$ as **groups** and suppose that they act on a same finite set, say $\Omega$. Can we see $G≇H$ as **permutation groups**. Honestly, I am intrested in this point in the following link. It is started by:

> Notice that different permutation groups may well be isomorphic as ....

[See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group#Isomorphisms)

Comment: I like this question! +1

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The definition of "isomorphic as permutation groups" given in the wikipedia page you refer to is equivalent to the images of $G$ and $H$ in their actions on $\Omega$ being conjugate in the symmetric group on $\Omega$.

You should be able to think of examples of subgroups $G$ and $H$ of $S_n$ for some $n$ such that $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic as groups, but not conjugate in $S_n$. Try groups of order 2 in $S_4$, for example.

Comment: Dear Prof.,here are two subgroups of $S_4$ of order two; Group([ (), (1,2) ]) and Group([ (), (1,2)(3,4) ]).

Comment: There you go, @Babak! Those two groups you mention are isomorphic as groups yet they act differently on $\,\{1,2,3,4\}\,$ and thus they are not isomorphic *as permutation groups*, according to Derek's definition, as they clearly are not conjugate subgroups of $\,S_4\,$

Comment: @DonAntonio: I got it from 2 answers here. Thanks for your comment. You always come suddenly and hint me nicely. :-)

Comment: Nice to know that, @Babak. +1 for yet another interesting question that, again, makes me think.

Comment: To clarify what is meant, it's not that the two groups act differently on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ that's important, but that the two actions are not isomorphic as $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$-sets.

Answer (score 13):

Let $G$ and $H$ act faithfully on a finite set $\Omega$. This is equivalent to say that $G$ and $H$ are subgroups of the total permutation group $\mathfrak S_\Omega$.

Here are two notion of isomorphism which are stronger than a simple group isomorphism :

1. The action of $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic if there exists a group morphism $\phi : G \to H$ and a bijection $\sigma : \Omega \to \Omega$ such that for all $g\in G$ and $x\in \Omega$
   $$ g\cdot \sigma x = \sigma(\phi g \cdot x). $$
   In particular, the morphism $\phi$ is an isomorphism, because if $\phi g = 1$ then for all $x\in\Omega$ $g\cdot \sigma x = \sigma x$, and since the action of $G$ is faithful and $\sigma$ surjective, this implies that $g = 1$.
2. $G$ and $H$ are said to be conjugate in $\mathfrak S_\Omega$ is there exist a permutation $\sigma$ of $\Omega$ such that $G = \sigma H \sigma^{-1}$. In particular the map $g\in G \mapsto \sigma^{-1} g \sigma\in H$ is an isomorphism.

In fact, both notion are the same (easy exercise for you !), and its what Wikipedia call *permutation group isomorphism*.

This notion is strictly stronger that the notion of *group isomorphism*. For example, take $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\}$, $G$ the group of order $2$ generated by the transposition $(1 2)$ and $H$ the group of order $2$ generated by the double transposition $(1 2)(3 4)$. As groups, $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic, because they are both isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. **However, they are not isomorphic as permutation group**. Indeed, the conjugate of a transposition is always a transposition, it cannot be a double transposition. More precisely, the conjugate $\sigma (1 2) \sigma^{-1}$ is the transposition $(\sigma 1, \sigma 2)$.

When classifying the subgroups of a given group, it is often important to classify them *up to isomorphism* but also *up to conjugation*, because isomorphism class can split into several conjugation classes.

Comment: Before I could see your nice answer, I was taking groups $H$ and $G$ as you noted kindly. May I deduce that since $G$ is transitive on $\Omega$ and the other group is not, so they are not isomorphic as permutaion groups? I got more than I had expected. Thanks.

Comment: @BabakSorouh — That would have been a good reason to say that G and H are not isomorphic actions, however H is not transitive since 2 can only be send on itself or on 1. But it is true that H fixes no points, whereas G fixes 2 points (3 and 4), so they cannot be isomorphic.

Comment: You probably want to use the word "transposition" instead of "permutation".

Comment: @GenericHuman — I do, thank you for pointing it out.