# Do orders uniquely describe a group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Three finite groups with the same numbers of elements of each order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62331/three-finite-groups-with-the-same-numbers-of-elements-of-each-order)

With any finite group $G$ I can associate a multiset $S_G = \{\text{ord}(g) : g \in G\}$. Is the map $G \mapsto S_G$ injective? Is there an algorithm to generate a multiplication table of $G$ from $S_G$? Given any multiset $S$, how hard is it to check if it represents some group in this way?

Having tried a few groups, it does look like an injection, but a formal proof or a construction (brute force aside) escapes me.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39848/finite-groups-with-elements-of-the-same-order

Comment: In short, there do exist both finite non-abelian groups and abelian groups of the same order in which all non-trivial elements have order $p$, for some primes $p$.

Comment: This is clearly false, as other have pointed out- it fails badly for $p$-groups for odd $p.$ I believe it is an open question if attention is restricted to finite simple groups.

Comment: Well, that's a pity. My last questions remains somewhat relevant though. (Given any multiset S, how hard is it to check if it represents some group in this way?).

Comment: See this for complete source as @Derek Holt showed. http://math.stackexchange.com/q/159395/8581

Comment: This question is an exact duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181632/, which has been closed as a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62331/three-finite-groups-with-the-same-numbers-of-elements-of-each-order (although that really is a different question). Since the system will not allow me to vote to close this questoin as a duplicate of the first one, I'll vote to close it as a duplicate of the second one. By the way I found this because I was looking for a much more recent duplicate that I saw, but searching is so miserable that I cannot find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a simple counterexample, $\mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_4$, $\mathbb{Z}_4\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_4$, and $Q_8\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ all have the same multisets of element orders.  In general, the list of element orders does not tell you very much about a group's structure.

I addressed your second question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/223281/12952) and your third question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/292473/12952).